# How to hide links in a page when user is not allowed to view the page set by privilege policy?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web site I can create users and assign certain pages to that user.  So for example when I assign WebpageA to user1, this user won't be able to view WebpageB and WebpageC (it will display a 401 message when trying to view the other two pages).

So this is now my problem.  How do I hide the other two pages from the menu so that user1 only sees WebpageA in the drop down by the menu?

This is some of the code I have (please feel free to ask for more if you require more code)

menu.ascx

```
<li class="panel">
        <a id="lnkWebpages" runat="server" href="#webpages" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav-menu" class="collapsed"><i class="ti-files"></i><span class="title">Pages</span> <i class="icon-submenu ti-angle-left"></i></a>
        <div id="webpages" class="collapse">
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a id="lnkWebpage4" runat="server" href="~/webpages/WebpageA.aspx">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="lnkWebpage5" runat="server" href="~/webpages/WebpageB.aspx">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="lnkWebpage6" runat="server" href="~/webpages/WebpageC.aspx">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Menu.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["Privilege"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtPrivilege = (DataTable)Session["Privilege"];
            foreach (DataRow dRow in dtPrivilege.Rows)
            {
                if (dRow[0].ToString().Equals("users.aspx"))
                {
                    isAddPermission = bool.Parse(dRow[1].ToString());
                    isDeletePermission = bool.Parse(dRow[2].ToString());
                    isModifyPermission = bool.Parse(dRow[3].ToString());
                    isReadPermission = bool.Parse(dRow[4].ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (isReadPermission.Equals(false))
        {
            lnkUsers.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            lnkUsers.Visible = true;
        }

        /* Enable / Disable Menu Items */
        if (Session["Privilege"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtPrivilege = (DataTable)Session["Privilege"];

            /* Dashboard */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[0]["FormName"].ToString() == "dashboard.aspx")
                lnkDashboard.Visible = false;

            /* Settings */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[1]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[1]["FormName"].ToString() == "general.aspx")
                lnkSettings.Visible = false;

            /* Web Pages */
            if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[2]["Read"].ToString()) == false &&
                bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[3]["Read"].ToString()) == false &&
                bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[4]["Read"].ToString()) == false)
                lnkWebpages.Visible = false;

            else
            {
                if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[5]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[5]["FormName"].ToString() == "WebpageA.aspx")
                    lnkWebpage4.Visible = false;
                if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[6]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[6]["FormName"].ToString() == "WebpageB.aspx")
                    lnkWebpage5.Visible = false;
                if (bool.Parse(dtPrivilege.Rows[4]["Read"].ToString()) == false && dtPrivilege.Rows[4]["FormName"].ToString() == "WebpageC.aspx")
                    lnkWebpage6.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally { }
}
protected void lnkProfile_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strEncrypedUserId = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DataControl.Encrypt(Session["userId"].ToString()));
        Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/users/profile.aspx?uid={0}", strEncrypedUserId));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toastr.ShowToast(ex.Message, "Error", Toastr.Type.Error);
    }
    finally { }
}
```

}

In the database:

```
| form_id_pk     |  form_name    | Description  |
-------------------------------------------------
|    7           | WebpageA.aspx | Page 1       |
-------------------------------------------------
|    8           | WebpageB.aspx | Page 2       |
-------------------------------------------------
|    9           | WebpageC.aspx | Page 3       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

If you require more code please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First hide all the menu:

```
<li class="panel">
        <a id="lnkWebpages" runat="server" href="#webpages" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar-nav-menu" class="collapsed"><i class="ti-files"></i><span class="title">Pages</span> <i class="icon-submenu ti-angle-left"></i></a>
        <div id="webpages" class="collapse">
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a id="lnkWebpage4" runat="server" href="~/webpages/WebpageA.aspx" visible="false">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a id="lnkWebpage5" runat="server" href="~/webpages/WebpageB.aspx" visible="false">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a id="lnkWebpage6" runat="server" href="~/webpages/WebpageC.aspx" visible="false">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</li>
```

Then in code behind, you have `userId` in Session i.e. `Session["userId"]`:

```
/* Here we are getting the data from Database */

    public DataTable GetDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string constring = "";//Your Connection...;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT form_id_pk,form_name,Description FROM tblTableName where form_id_pk='"+Session["userId"] + "'", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using ( dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

In Page Load....call the above method for getting the data....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dtGetData = GetDataTable();

         Note:- As per your Table Data structure ...one user have only one Page Access...
                 User Only Get only one Row....check separately... one easy method...   

            if (dtGetData != null && dtGetData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dtGetData.Rows[0]["form_name"] == "WebpageA.aspx")
                {
                    lnkWebpage4.Visible = true;  //Here Other 2 menu will be Hide....
                }

                else if (dtGetData.Rows[0]["form_name"] == "WebpageB.aspx")
                {
                    lnkWebpage5.Visible = true;
                }

                else if (dtGetData.Rows[0]["form_name"] == "WebpageC.aspx")
                {
                    lnkWebpage6.Visible = true;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```